# Load Multiple JSONStore in 1 page

Tags: c#, extjs

im new in ExtJs and i user c# as the handler, i have a problem, when my js load multiple store in 1 page, it always load only the latest store that I declare, the other one never get load, i have tried to set the first store autoload config options into false then reload the store when the other store is loaded, but it doesnt work, the first store never execute the handler to get the data, is there any sample code to fix this problem?

Comment: We need to see some code to help.

Answer (score 0):

```
var store = new Ext.data.Store({
    model: ...,    
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url : ...,
        actionMethods :{
        read   : 'POST'
        }
        ...
    }
});
```

Try this. This works fine and loads every store u create.